# Why the electromagnetic waves propagate and do not stand still?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I know that the electromagnetic waves are alternating electric and magnetic fields.  But I don't get why they can't stand still and alternate at the same point.  I would like a logical and verbal answer rather than a mathematical answer.  But if mathematics helps to explain the logical answer then it's fine.

19/12/15
Just now I found a one possible answer to my above question.  It's not that easy to understand but looks credible.  I found it in the book:  The Transactional Interpretation Of Quantum Mechanics - The Reality Of Possibility by Ruth E Kastner, page 198

Ruth E Kastner says:
"In some sense, energy is only propagated due to the possibility of complex energies –
corresponding to virtual particles or “propagators” in relativistic field theories. This
subtlety concerning the ontology of energy propagation is routinely overlooked in
most discussions of Green’s functions and their various forms, and again suggests
that sub-empirical processes, corresponding to the complex energy values, are in
play in any propagation of actual (real) energy."

Comment: The short answer is "because photons are massless." Unfortunately understanding why that actually answers the question presupposes a lot of background, and it really just moves the question down one level, since you could just as well ask why photons are massless.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all waves systems are based on tendency to transfer the "inconsistency" (it doesn't matter whether it is tension, pressure, voltage...). There should not be a place in a continuum with higher relative energy density than its neighborhood maintained by nothing. The energy will spread and try to be "averaged out" - there will be no standing wave without a reflection!

But there is a little "but" in this. What I have just described would be valid for e.g. a heat equation as well. For that I would recommend reading about the differences between parabolic and [hyperbolic partial differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation).

**Mathematically:** You can write wave equation

$$
\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-\frac{1}{c_0^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)\psi=0
$$

as "a product" of two advection equations:

$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{c_0}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{c_0}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)\psi=0
$$

with the meaning of transporting the excitement to the left and right (in 1D case - could be generalised).

Answer (score 1):

By definition, waves are propagating oscillations. Still, standing waves do exists, which are equivalent to the superimposition of two propagating waves in opposite direction. E.g. inside a microwave oven you can consider that this is the case.

Also since velocity inside materials depends on refraction index and since propagation relates to group velocity that relates on derivative of optic properties with wavelength, you can design some very strange material when an EM wave of a very precise frequency get slowed at arbitrary speed, almost stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The recent quote is irrelevant to the velocit c of the electromagnetic waves.

> I know that the electromagnetic waves are alternating electric and magnetic fields.

[image]

> The [electromagnetic wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation)  can be imagined as a self-propagating transverse oscillating wave of electric and magnetic fields. This 3D animation shows a plane linearly polarized wave propagating from left to right. Note that the electric and magnetic fields in such a wave are in-phase with each other, reaching minima and maxima together

```
....
```

> But I don't get why they can't stand still and alternate at the same point.

It is an observational experimental fact that electromagnetic waves in vacuum or near vacuum travel [with speed c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light). In a medium the index of refraction  n of the material (n = c / v). modifies the group velocity of the wave but this is not particularly relevant to the question.

One could design standing waves

> [Standing waves are also observed in optical media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave#Light) such as optical wave guides, optical cavities, etc. Lasers use [optical cavities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_cavity) in the form of a pair of facing mirrors. The gain medium in the cavity (such as a crystal) emits light coherently, exciting standing waves of light in the cavity.  But this is also not part of your question the, wave is still moving with velocity c, it is just synchronized in space.
>
> I would like a logical and verbal answer rather than a mathematical answer.

Well the real answer is *because that is what has been observed in nature*,  electromagnetic waves move with velocity c=299792458 meters/second.

Comment: I did not ask why the EM waves velocity is C.  I just asked why those waves travel at all.  So the quote I gave is very relevant.  It shows what I was suspecting for a long time -- that the EM waves and their properties conceal far deeper physical mysteries than even Einstein or anybody else could been able to touch yet.  Their basic properties seem to be concerned with some unresolved physical entities and phenomena like the authentic nature of space, the Quantum effects, zero-point energy, extra dimensions -- all those issues which the cutting-edge Physics is struggling with today.

Comment: @YM2015 If something is measured to be always moving it cannot sit still, this is elementary logic. The quote is about propagators and there is nothing mysterious about them, they are a mathematical representation within the functions that calculate crossections and lifetimes to be compared with experiment. The mystery will be the fuzzy mathematical background of the author.

Comment: @ anna v
The propagators and other complex mathematical representations are indicators of complex physical reality.  That’s precisely one of the major arguments in that book.  Also your opening argument in your last reply is nothing but a vacant play of words and not an attempt to answer my original question.  And your last sentence is an unnecessary insulting remark towards the author of the book.

Comment: Look, I do not belong to the platonic school "mathematics creates reality". I am an experimentalist and believe that mathematics is a tool used to model physical measurements, that is all. When people start being mystical about mathematics, I sign off.

Comment: In Physics, it has already been proven that mathematics can sometimes foresee unknown physical realities, like in the famous case of anti-matter which was predicted to exist before anybody discovered it or even imagined it in the scientific world.  You are entitled to restrict your thinking within whatever limits you choose.  But the reality of the physical world has shown many times in the past that it refuses to obey the human mind’s limits and restrictions.

Comment: There’s no need to choose to be mystical with mathematics and physics.  They lead to the so called “mystical” realities by their own merits, suggesting us to discard our traditional limited concepts about the physical reality.  Mathematics does not create reality.  Mathematics is just the best available tool we have created to assist ourselves to measure, and also to explore, the reality.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a rope in your hand that is tied to a brick wall.  Give it a flick and a wave will travel down it.  Now consider how you could get a standing wave between you and the wall.  You can't do it (as Victor Pira points out the mechanics of the wave is to travel) unless you have a more complex superposition of multiple waves (this to me is cheating, you're using many photons to give the impression of a standing wave).

So my answer is that whatever the underlying laws of physics are, they only allow travelling waves (intuitively imagine an endless grid of ropes).  As anna v points out this is also what has been empirically observed.

Sorry, not much of an answer I know.  The thing I find fascinating is considering electron orbitals (or even atoms) as a kind of complex standing wave (a superposition of many waves in a stable configuration).  Then thinking about the relationship between energy (a photon) and matter (an electron say).  How does a photon (a travelling wave) change/interact with an electron (an arrangement of standing waves?)...

[image: Electron orbitals]